# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT -ANDROID RETROFIT2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have seen this question several times asked in stackoverflow.but those answers not fixed my issue and i'm new to retrofit.i'm using retrofit for my login interface.i'm sending username,password then response will be two tokens inside a array.when i trying to login,log cat showing `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`

**Request**

POST : form-urlencorded

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AllConstants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


  public void getUser(String username,String password){

        WebserviceAPI apiService =retrofit.create(WebserviceAPI.class);
        Call<UserResponse> call = apiService.getUsers("signin",username,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                UserResponse result = response.body();
                Log.d("res",""+result.getData());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("res",""+t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

Model class

```
public class User {

    String id;
    String username;
    String email;
    String access_token;
    String refresh_token;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAccess_token() {
        return access_token;
    }

    public void setAccess_token(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    public String getRefresh_token() {
        return refresh_token;
    }

    public void setRefresh_token(String refresh_token) {
        this.refresh_token = refresh_token;
    }

}
```

**UserResponse.java**

```
public class UserResponse {
    List<User> data;

    public List<User> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<User> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface WebserviceAPI {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("auth")
    Call<UserResponse> getUsers(@Field("module_action") String signin ,@Field("username") String username,@Field("password") String password);
}
```

**Response from server side : PHP**

```
$response = ['status' => true,
            'message' => "Successfully logged in",
            'data' => [
              'access_token' => $accessToken,
              'refresh_token' => $refreshToken
            ],
          ];
            $this->returnJson($response, 200);
```

when i run in Postman,response is like below

[image]

**--------Update-----------**

some response contain only `status` and `message`.

response eg :

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Inactive User"
}
```

then i want to get `message`.

i have edited `UserResponse` as below and tried to get `message`.then showing `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.app.myapp.Login$3.onResponse(Login.java:92)`

```
 public class UserResponse {
        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private String status;
    
        @SerializedName("message")
        @Expose
        private String message;
    
        User data;
    
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
    
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
    
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    
        public User getData() {
            return data;
        }
    
        public void setData(User data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    
    }

public void getUser(String username,String password){

        WebserviceAPI apiService =retrofit.create(WebserviceAPI.class);
        Call<UserResponse> call = apiService.getUsers("signin",username,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                UserResponse result = response.body();
                //User data = result.getData();
                Log.d("userresponse",""+result.getMessage());
              
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("res",""+t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Kindly provide the stack trace or error log

Comment: In your JSON 'data' is not a list it is an object. So try to remove list<user> data and use User data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Postman response data field is coming as a JSON Object, not as a JSON array. If this is the case and you are using "data" field as a list in your UserResponse model, it will not be able to map it. This is the issue i think. To solve it you can use below UserResponse data model :

```
public class UserResponse {
    User data;

    public User getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(User data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: i can get data object using `User data = result.getData();` .so how can i get `message` ?

Comment: Add a string variable named message to UserResponse and add its getter and setter

Comment: some response coming without data,those response contain only status and message.i have added message to UserResponse then i tried result.getMessage().but it's showing java.lang.NullPointerException. ihave updated my question.

Comment: Can you paste the response you are getting in that case and the stack trace of the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT -ANDROID RETROFIT2`
 i.e the response or the JSON received is an Object where you are trying to access it as an array.

Change your server code to

```
$response[] = array('status' => true,
            'message' => "Successfully logged in",
            'data' => [
              'access_token' => $accessToken,
              'refresh_token' => $refreshToken
            ],
          );

echo json_encode($response);
```

Expected response is

```
[{"status":true,"message":"Successfully logged in","data":{"access_token":null,"refresh_token":null}}]
```

Which is an array